# no puedo guardar nombre al registrar un usuario - Firebase y javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web

```js
function crear() {
  var auth = firebase.auth();
  nombre = $("#NombrePerfil").val();
  correo1 = $("#correo1").val();
  password1 = $("#clave1").val();
  password2 = $("#clave2").val();
  if (password1 == password2) {
    password = $("#clave1").val();
  } else {
    alertify.error("Las contraseñas NO son iguales");
    return 0;
  }
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(correo1, password).then(function(authData) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var photo = PhotoUpload();

    user.updateProfile({
      displayName: nombre,
      photoURL: photo
    }).then(function() {
      alertify.success("¡Gracias Por Registrarte!");
    }, function(error) {
      alertify.error(error.message);
    });

  }).catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    if (errorCode == "auth/email-already-in-use") {
      alertify.error("El correo ya esta en uso");
    }
    if (errorCode == "auth/weak-password") {
      alertify.error("Contraseña muy vurnerable, 6 digitos minimo!.");
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<form method="#" action="#" onsubmit="crear(); return false">
  <div class="card card-login card-hidden">
    <div class="card-header text-center" data-background-color="rose">
      <h4 class="card-title">Registro</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <img id="ImagenPreview" class="img-thumbnail" src="img/defaul.jpg" style="width: 40%;height: auto;" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group" style="display:none;">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
      <input type="file" id="foto" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                                                </span>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
          <label class="control-label">Nombre</label>
          <input id="NombrePerfil" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="material-icons">email</i>
                                            </span>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
          <label class="control-label">Email</label>
          <input id="correo1" type="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                            </span>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
          <label class="control-label">Contraseña</label>
          <input id="clave1" type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                            </span>
        <div class="form-group label-floating">
          <label class="control-label">Repita Contraseña</label>
          <input id="clave2" type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-simple btn-pinterest">
                                            Registrarme
                                            <div class="ripple-container"></div>
                                        </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

estoy tratando de guardar un usuario con varios datos y no puedo guardar el nombre algo tengo malo que no puedo encontrar el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pone el codigo para que te puedan ayudar editando tu propio codigo

Comment: ok! lo acabo de editar

Comment: que error te aparece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al estar todo en la misma función pasa todo muy rápido, pon el `uptadeProfile` dentro de un `then` al finalizar la función "`crear()`", o bien puedes hacer un `setTimeOut` de unos 2 segundos.

Esto pasa porque el `uptadeProfile` necesita un usuario activo, pero el `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` tarda un poco en devolver el `user` actual,